# how to fetch top 3 records from collection in Mongodb.?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I want to fetch top 3 records in mondo db. but I am getting all the record
`Select top 3 From airbnb;`
my mongo query is
`db.listingandreview.find().limit(3)`
I am getting all the 5555 records where I only want top 3.

Thanks

Comment: this should be correct please show your code

Comment: I am using mongo shell(5.) to run this query, ```db.listingandreview.find().limit(3)``` in cmd

Comment: I only want to display the first 3 listings.

Comment: yes please post all of your code

Comment: I had connected to the mongo atlas and loaded the sample datasets from it. and lastly I connected that cluster in mogoshell. ```show dbs```, ```use sample_airbnb```,```show collections``` , than I wrote ```db.listingAndReviews.find({}).limit(3)``` this all my code is. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method:
db.collection.find().limit();
Or
let query = write whateverquery you want to apply;
db.collection.find(query).limit(3);

Note: If you gives a value of limit 0,it means there is no limit

Comment: I had try this ```db.foo.find({},{column_name:1}).limit(3)``` this is how it worked, gone trough the documents. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `aggregate` function

```
db1.aggregate([
        { $limit: 4}
    ]).toArray();
```